# What is $\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}\frac{f(x,y)-f(0,0)}{\|(x,y)\|}$?

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f\in C^1(\mathbb R^2)$. What is the limit $$\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}\frac{f(x,y)-f(0,0)}{\|(x,y)\|}\ \ ?$$

It looks to be the definition of a kind of derivative, but since $f:\mathbb R^2\longrightarrow \mathbb R$, it looks strange... Is there a name for this limit ?

Comment: @MarkViola The derivative of $f$ at $(0,0),$ if it exists, is a linear transformation, not a number. The limit of the OP usually doesn't exist. It exists iff $\nabla f (0,0)$ is the zero vector.

Answer (score 1):

That defines a "kind of" derivative of $f$ at $(0,0)$ **if** the derivative there exists and is $(0,0)$. In particular, if the derivative exists and is $(0,0)$, then your limit is $0$.

I should mention that while I've said this is a "kind of" derivative, it's really not at all useful, since it only exists when the real derivative is $(0,0)$.

To see that it does not necessarily exist even when the derivative exists but happens to be *non*zero, 
consider $f(x, y) = x^2+x$, and look at your limit as $(x, y) \to (0,0)$ for $x > 0$ and $y = 0$. You get $\frac{x^2+x}{x} = x+1 \to 1$. But now look at it for $x < 0$ and $y = 0$: you get $\frac{x^2 + x}{-x} = -x -1 \to -1$. (Why the $-x$ in the denominator? Because $\|(x,0)\| = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2} = |x| = -x$ when $x$ is negative.) These two limits are not equal, and your overall limit does not exist, even though $f$ is clearly differentiable at $0$ (with derivative $(1, 0)$).

Comment: The first sentence is wrong. See my comment above.

Comment: Fixed -- I typed too fast. Thanks for catching that.